# Is it possible to do the opposite of USERELATIONSHIP in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, relationship, powerbi-desktop

I have a DAX code called `DateDiff` that checks count of days between the campaign start and end date that fall within the calendar date slicer which worked fine.

However, upon doing more testing I noticed it returns an incorrect number due to the direction its travelling in based on the relationship.

```
DateDiff = 
VAR selectmin =
    MIN ( CalendarTable[Calendar Date])
VAR selectmax =
    MAX (CalendarTable[Calendar Date])
VAR firstDateSelect =
    IF ( selectmin <= [mincheck], [mincheck], selectmin )
VAR secondDateSelect =
    IF ( selectmax >= [maxcheck], [maxcheck], selectmax )
RETURN
         DATEDIFF ( firstDateSelect - 1, secondDateSelect, DAY )
```

**Current Relationship:**

[image]

[image]

**Expected Result (Without turning the relationship to inactive)**

[image]

[image]

So the expected number should be `105`, but its currently returning 104 because the range table is filtering the overview table to get that number, rather I need the calculation to somehow turn that relationship off just for that particular measure so that it can travel upwards so that the correct number can be returned.

I initially thought to use `USERELATIONSHIP` but this function is only when you have an inactive relationship and you want to turn it on, whilst I am looking for a way to do the opposite and turn off an active relationship or ignore it just for that specific measure.

Is this possible in Power Bi?

*Note: I need the measure to travel in the direction of the blue lines*

PBIX File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19K7v0hoXpeNuW9ldENzK65Ht8im9OjcM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use [CROSSFILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/crossfilter-function) and set the direction to None

Example:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(table), CROSSFILTER(table[id],table2[id],None))
```

Comment: I actually tried that and it still returns 104 but it should return 105, it only works when I manually turn the relationship to inactive